# How can I direct a url to a subdomain?

Tags: url-rewriting, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that I host for multiple users as useraccount.mysite.com.  I want to have the option to allow my users to have their own url (useraccount.com) but still host the app using my shared server.  So they should be able to access useraccount.mysite.com or useraccount.com and it should return the same stuff.  If they goto useraccount.com, the url should always say useraccount.com and they should never see mysite.com.

Is this possible?

Comment: I would post this on ServerFault to get the part of your question about setting up the [username].mysite.com DNS entry. The rest we can help you with.